# Create XML in an iOS app programatically to save it as a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, sqlite

I was to create XML as below and save it as a string. The values for the XML will be from sqlite database. I want to pass the string value which will be in a xml format through a WebService, so for that reason I want to create XML and save it as a string. Please help me with this.

**1st XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EmployeeHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <EmplID>1001</EmplID>
    <EmplName>Jack</EmplName>
    <Designation>Manager</Designation>
    <Department>Sales</Department>
</EmployeeHeader>
```

**2nd XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EmployeeDetail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Address>
       <City>Philadelphia</City>
       <State>PA</State>
       <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
</EmployeeDetail>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you're asking, but if I'm understanding you correctly, you just want to build an XML string substituting the values you get from a database?

Something like:

```
NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<EmployeeDetail><Address><City>%@</City><State>%@</State><Country>%@</Country></Address>", addr.city, addr.state, addr.country];
```

Comment: In my app I have a button sync. So it will sync all the details of the form which was stored in sqlite database to my central server. To do that, I have a webservice which takes string parameters. But these string values will be in a xml format. If I pass properly formatted xml as a string through the webservice then the data will be saved in the central server.What can I do for this?

Comment: Still not clear what the problem is.  I understand English is not your primary language - maybe post some code that you have tried so I can get a better understanding of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I will explain in more detailed way. I have a form where I have 2 buttons, sync and save. Save button would save all the entered data of the form in sqlite database. Later on, whenever the user wants to save the data in the central database outside iOS, he/she will hit the sync button, which will call a webservice and will take string parameters. The webservice is designed in such a way that, it will take string parameters but should be in XML. I want to create XML of the data in the sqlite and then save it as string so I can pass it through the webservice.

Comment: If your question is "how to I create an XML string", then see this answer.  If your question is "how do I call a web service", then you'll need to edit the question to indicate that.  If the question is something else, then you'll need to clarify it better.  Post some code showing what you're trying to do, and explain exactly what isn't working.

Comment: My question is very clear on How to create XML string. I just wanted to know how can I create XML string for the values which are stored in my sqlite database. Anyways I have found some solutions online using some 3rd party classes. Thanks a lot.